# how to clear data of bootstrap modal at the time of submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use this ajax code for submit data on model but model is not clear without reloading page

```
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:   {phone_no:phone,note:note,todate:todate,fromdate:fromdate},
       url:'calls_note.php',
       success:function(data) {
                if(data == 1)
                {
                    $('#info3').hide();
                    $('#err_msg').show().children('div').html("Error in updating Note").show().fadeOut(10000);
                    $('#info').hide();
                }       
                else
                {
                    $('#info3').hide();
                    $('#err_msg').hide();
                    $('#info').hide();
        $('#table_div').html(data);
        $('.table').dataTable();
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        $(this).removeData('#myModal');


                }
           }
      });
```

plz tell me what i do how to clear modal data without reload the page

Comment: Does your modal use a `<form>` tag? Does it have an `ID` on it? If so, look at how to reset a form with javascript, that's your easiest solution.

Comment: please provide HTML code

Comment: How did your code indentation come to be like this? The more I work with people the more baffled I get at how some people don't care about... code hygiene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this source code of line please

```
$('#myModal form :input').val("");
```

this code will clear data after submitting you data successfully. Place this code in success function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#myModal .modal-body").html('');
```

this will replace the content of .modal-body to empty

**Edit:**
if you Want to Clear Form in the Model Try this

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```

Comment: He wants to clear the modal data (form fields, I presume). Not empty the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$('#your_form_id').find('input:text').val(''); 
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');//in case if you have check box in your form`